# Append child not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendchild, createelement

I'm trying to append a div to an un-ordered list but the div appended and previously created has trouble showing up. Any ideas why?

Thanks so much to anyone who can help!

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="buttonone" class="add"><b><span>Add</span></b>
</button>
<ul id = "all"></ul>
```

CSS:

```
#woow{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
 #buttonone {
     opacity: 0;
     position: relative;
     left: 78%;
     top: 23px;
     font-family:"Roboto";
     height: 38px;
     width: 100px;
     background-color: #5dade2;
     color: white;
     border-radius: 2px;
     font-size: 22px;
     outline: 0px solid transparent;
     border: 0px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
     -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
     transition: all 0.15s linear;
 }
```

JS:

```
$('#text').fadeTo(0, 1);
$('#text').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
setTimeout(function()
{
    $('#buttonone').fadeTo(0, 1);
    $('#buttonone').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
}, 100);
$('#buttoneone').click(function(){
    var list = document.getElementById('all');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "woow";
    list.appendChild(div);
});
```

Comment: why do you append a div element into a ul? do you mean li?

Comment: Side note, typo. `$('#buttoneone').click(function(){` should be `$('#buttonone').click(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery already - no need to use `getElementById/createElement/appendChild`. Oh and only LI element can be a direct child of UL (you might be able to add a DIV, but it won't be a valid HTML). Try this:

```
$('#buttonone').click(function(){
    $('#all').append($('<li><div id="woow"/></li>'));
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WN649/1/**

Answer (score 0):

in using the appendChild you have to put your script type = text/js below the div you are trying to affect.

a simple code to try this with is...
this creates whatever element you want to add
var varname = document.createElement("div");

varname.innerHTML = "Did You Know?";

document.getElementById("buttonone").appendChild(varname);